# Generate a unique identifier based on last inserted id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create something like JIRA, which is used for bug reporting tool.

While creating tickets, I need to insert a ticket identifier to the ticket_details table. This identifier will have a prefix, something as 'LM' and then then ticket_id. 
Example: LM001

```
$ticket_data = array();
$ticket_data['client_id'] = $client->client_id;

$ticket_data['stage_id'] = 1;
$ticket_data['creator_id'] = 3;
$ticket_data['assigned_id'] = $request->input('assigned_to');

$ticket = Tickets::create($ticket_data);
$identifier = $ticket_data['ticket_identifier'] = 'LT'.$ticket->ticket_id;
print_r($identifier);
$ticket->save();
print_r($ticket_data);
```

How can I insert this identifier while inserting the rest of the information??

Comment: First save, then get ID, then set ticket_identifier, then save again. `$identifier = $ticket_data['ticket_identifier'] = 'LT'.$ticket->ticket_id;` is also really weird. Should be something like `$ticket_data['ticket_identifier'] = 'LT'.$ticket->ticket_id;`

Comment: You will have to first make in the other records into the table, then fetch the ID of the last inserted record and then update the ticket_id using the extracted ID

Comment: Or maybe use a GUID http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Comment: Why would you even have to do it in the first place? It's redundant, you already have PK, this identifier you're talking about does nothing. You're even basing it on the id. Why would you complicate your life for literally **no reason**?

Comment: @N.B. It's a "natural key"/"domain key". It's for humans, not databases. It's easier to refer to bug "ZAP-1337" than a guid. It may also contain other information than the primary key, such as project-name/key and a counter, like Jira does.

Comment: @SimonSvensson - still makes no sense. You can always show the "human" key without saving it to database, it's trivial. Also, I see no reason why `LM001` is any more "human" than simply showing `1` or even `001`.  The key we're talking about here is based on surrogate key, so what's the point in creating a "human" key? Still, it must be just me who dislikes creating more work for no reason. Stupid, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you have ticket_id you can simply update record like:

```
$ticket_data['ticket_identifier'] = 'LT'.$ticket->ticket_id;
$updateTicket = Tickets::find($ticket->ticket_id)->update($ticket_data);//updating here
```

Another way:

```
$ticket = Tickets::create($ticket_data);
$ticket->ticket_identifier = 'LT'.$ticket->ticket_id;
$ticket->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the insertGetId method to save the record and have the idea returned, which you could then use for the ticket identifier.